# Format String C++ in CreateProcess

Tags: c++, createprocess

ello all I hope someone can help me with this issue I am using the following example from msdn for createprocess function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

This is accessed via dos and works perfectly using this command in command prompt. When I type this

this.exe "my.exe test" > result.txt

The my.exe is another console application that takes the input test and the > result.txt is for my output log. I am trying to remove the need for the command line so I am trying to feed the path into the createprocess function call. This is where I get stuck here is what I am trying

```
if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "\"my.exe test \" > result.txt",        // this.exe "my.exe test" > result.txt
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
```

still doesnt work I thought \" would give me the result I needed but it doesnt seem to work, will parse the my.exe and test part but not the > result.txt output. However it works from the command prompt fine if i pass it to argv[1].

Any help much appreciated.

So in summary

In console I can parse

```
this.exe "my.exe test" > result.txt // Works fine via cmd.exe
```

To app I tried

```
my.exe test > result.txt // Not work but missing ""
```

and

```
\"my.exe test \" > result.txt // work for first section
```

Answer (score 3):

`CreateProcess` only does basic command line parsing by breaking up the words into individual arguments -- it doesn't understand file redirection or anything.  If you pass it `"> result.txt"`, it tries to parse that as two arguments named literally `">"` and `"result.txt"`.

If you want to redirect the output of the command, you have two options:

1. Do the redirection yourself.  To do that, you'd first open the file with `CreateFile` (passing in security attributes which make the handle inheritable), and then assign the resulting handle to the `hStdOut` member of the `STARTUPINFO` structure you pass in.  Then, remember to close the file after `CreateProcess` returns, since otherwise you'd leak a handle.
2. Use another program to do the redirection.  When you type in commands on the command line, it's `cmd.exe` which parses your command line and does the file redirection.  So instead of creating a `my.exe` process, you could instead create a `cmd.exe` process with a command line something like this:

   ```
   cmd.exe "my.exe test > result.txt"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`CreateProcess` only expects an executable name and some arguments.  The redirection is actually not a program argument.  That is interpreted by the shell (`cmd.exe`).

What is happening when you invoke your own program is as follows...

```
cmd> this.exe "my.exe test" > result.txt

argv[0] = "this.exe"
argv[1] = "my.exe test"
Output is sent to result.txt by the shell
```

Now, your one that doesn't work:

```
cmd> this.exe my.exe test > result.txt

argv[0] = "this.exe"
argv[1] = "my.exe"
argv[2] = "test"
Output is sent to result.txt by the shell
```

You'll see that because you only send `argv[1]` to `CreateProcess`, the behaviour is not as you expected.

Now, as I mentioned, `CreateProcess` does not actually redirect output.  To do that, you should use the `system` call which invokes `cmd.exe` or whatever command interpreter the system uses:

```
system( "my.exe test > result.txt" );
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: adam paddy many thanks for the replys guys I now can see where i went wrong the reason I am using this function is because I didnt want the black dos box to pop up when I called the .exe file which it does when I use the system function. My app is WINAPI is there a better solution guys?

Comment: Well, as Adam suggested you can run `cmd.exe` from `CreateProcess`.  In addition, you could try setting the window visibility flags in the `STARTUPINFO` struct.  There are two places you need to do this (one to provide the flag, and another to tell it you have provided the flag).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: CreatePipe to read output from the created process, and then write data to a file: https://github.com/milasudril/gabi/blob/master/pots/pipein/pipein-win32.cpp Note the comment about CreateProcessW!